# How do I avoid time leakage in my KNN model?

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret, knn

I am building a KNN model to predict housing prices. I'll go through my data and my model and then my problem.

Data -

```
# A tibble: 81,334 x 4
   latitude longitude close_date          close_price
      <dbl>     <dbl> <dttm>                    <dbl>
 1     36.4     -98.7 2014-08-05 06:34:00     147504.
 2     36.6     -97.9 2014-08-12 23:48:00     137401.
 3     36.6     -97.9 2014-08-09 04:00:40     239105.
```

Model -

```
library(caret)
training.samples <- data$close_price %>%
  createDataPartition(p = 0.8, list = FALSE)
train.data  <- data[training.samples, ]
test.data <- data[-training.samples, ]

model <- train(
  close_price~ ., data = train.data, method = "knn",
  trControl = trainControl("cv", number = 10),
  preProcess = c("center", "scale"),
  tuneLength = 10
)
```

My problem is time leakage. I am making predictions on a house using other houses that closed afterwards and in the real world I shouldn't have access to that information.

I want to apply a rule to the model that says, for each value `y`, only use houses that closed before the house for that `y`. I know I could split my test data and my train data on a certain date, but that doesn't quite do it.

Is it possible to prevent this time leakage, either in `caret` or other libraries for knn (like `class` and `kknn`)?

Comment: Can you make a reproducible example? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `caret`, `createTimeSlices` implements a variation of cross-validation adapted to time series (avoiding time leakage by rolling the forecasting origin).
Documentation is [here](http://topepo.github.io/caret/data-splitting.html#data-splitting-for-time-series).

In your case, depending on your precise needs, you could use something like this for a proper cross-validation:

```
your_data <- your_data %>% arrange(close_date)

tr_ctrl <- createTimeSlices(
  your_data$close_price, 
  initialWindow  = 10, 
  horizon = 1,
  fixedWindow = FALSE)

model <- train(
  close_price~ ., data = your_data, method = "knn",
  trControl = tr_ctrl,
  preProcess = c("center", "scale"),
  tuneLength = 10
)
```

EDIT:
if you have ties in the dates and want to having deals closed on the same day in the test and train sets, you can fix `tr_ctrl` before using it in `train`:

```
filter_train <- function(i_tr, i_te) {
  d_tr <- as_date(your_data$close_date[i_tr]) #using package lubridate
  d_te <- as_date(your_data$close_date[i_te])
  tr_is_ok <- d_tr < min(d_te)

  i_tr[tr_is_ok]
}

tr_ctrl$train <- mapply(filter_train, tr_ctrl$train, tr_ctrl$test)
```

Comment: When you predict the `i`th close price, in this example, doesn't the model still have access to homes that closed after that one?

Comment: No, only to the $i-1$ records before. See the picture in the link I included

Comment: I have multiple homes that close on the same day. When you set horizon = 1, does that mean the time slice will go until the next home or the next close date? I'm thinking I might want to set the first argument to my_data$close_date.

Comment: If you check with `View(caret::createTimeSlices)`, you will see that the first argument is only used for its length, so your suggestion won't work. Sorry but I don't have a direct answer for when there are ties in the timepoints